# Disable drag to another day in agendaDay view (fullCalendar)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

How can I disable drag to another day in fullCalendar? I use agendaDay and need only one day, but when I drug event on top they drag to another day.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '', //title
        right: ''
    },
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    //titleFormat: '[Hello, World!]',
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    groupByResource: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    resources: [
        {id: '0', title: '0'},
        {id: '1', title: '1'},
        {id: '2', title: '2'},
        {id: '3', title: '3'},
        {id: '4', title: '4'},
        {id: '5', title: '5'},
        {id: '6', title: '6'}
    ],
    unselectAuto: false,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    dayClick: function (date) {
        alert('clicked ' + date.format());
    },
    select: function (startDate, endDate) {
        alert('selected ' + startDate.format() + ' to ' + endDate.format());
    },
    events: [],
    eventClick: function (info) {
        console.log(info);
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/serhii-danovsky/pen/pmWweq
[image]

But I want

[image]

Comment: take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventAllow